# How to pass withCredentials option to Request?

Tags: cors, xmlhttprequest, http-authentication, preflight, node-request

According to the [CORS spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests), `withCredentials: true` can be set on an XHR or Fetch request to include authorization credentials in the pre-flight request.

I'm using the Request library (in the browser). How can I pass that property through? Simply including { `withCredentials` } in the options like this doesn't seem to work:

```
request.get({
   ...,
   auth: {...},
   withCredentials: true
})
```

Comment: *“According to the [CORS spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests), `withCredentials: true` can be set on an XHR or Fetch request to include authorization credentials in the pre-flight request.”* — Actually, that’s not what the CORS spec says. The spec says that authorization credentials must *never* be sent in preflight requests. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-credentials%E2%91%A5, which says, *“a CORS-preflight request never includes credentials”*.

Comment: Huh. I'm really confused. If credentials aren't included in the pre-flight request with `credentials: 'include'`, then...what does that flag even do?

Comment: That flag specifies to include the credentials in the actual GET request from you own code. I’ll expand on that in the answer to your other question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, I have confirmed that the `Request` library does indeed support the `withCredentials: true` option (or rather, one of its dependencies does), and it eventually gets translated into a `credentials: "include"` parameter passed to `fetch()`.

As noted in comments above, the behaviour of *that* is not what I was expecting, but the issue is not with Request.